# how to send a header with Direct Web Remoting (DWR) with engine.js?

Tags: java, dwr

Ive been trying to use engine.js with DWR to send a header with my request.

For this I am trying to use the preHook (that it is supposed to be triggered before the rest of other things are executed), and I need to send a header metag as parameter (with a value)

Checking the webiste http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/engine/index.html have a poor information (almost none) about headers, so, I have no idea how to have the correct format for this, any of you have done this before?

I need it to integrate it with my java app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the DWR documentation](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/engine/index.html), you should be able to set headers as one of the request options. For example:

```
dwr.engine.setHeaders({
  "Content-Type":"text/plain",
  "My-Special-Header":"some-value"
});
```

Or it seems you could do it per-request, like so:

```
Remote.singleMethod(params, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type":"text/plain",
    "My-Special-Header":"some-value"
  }
});
```